# How to take login credentials from user and push it in array as object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, registration

Hello I want to store username and password as an object in array. As of this time I have this code:

```
var loginCred = [
{
    username: "janhaxe23",
    password: "HaxeJan23"
}];

function LogIn() {
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

for(i = 0; i < loginCred.length; i++) {
    if(username == loginCred[i].username && password == loginCred[i].password) {
        window.alert("Login Successfully. Welcome "+ username);
        return;
    }
}
window.alert("Incorrect login credentials. Please try again.");}
```

Instead of creating an object directly in JS file I want the user to input their login credentials by clicking the "Register" button. Thank you.

Comment: you can do: ```var loginCred = [
{
    username: document.getElementById('username').value,
    password: document.getElementById('password').value
}];```

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll try it now.

Comment: @Kristian This does not make any sense. Then from which values you are going to compare ?

Comment: @janhaxe23 Your code looks correct only as you are getting username and password from user only. You need an object either from an API or hardcoded in your JS file for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
function register(){
 var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
 var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

 loginCred.push({
   username: username,
   password: password
 })

}
```

You can push values to an array like this